# Not seeing events with html generated by javascript. on click not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Someone posted this answered with a link to a non-solution.  It hasn't been answered.

I have js writing html from json using the same classes to display content.
for example:

```
 <!-- item 1 -->
 <div class="item">
   <div class="name">The Name 1</div>
   <div class="hidden">hidden info</div>
 </div>

 <!-- item 2 -->
 <div class="item">
   <div class="name">The Name 2</div>
   <div class="hidden">hidden info</div>
 </div><!-- item -->
```

With .hidden having a 'none' property in css.

My goal is to click on .name and have .hidden toggle on/off, I can only make this work if I manually put the html in the doc using:

```
$('.item').click(function(){
  $(this).find('.hidden').toggle(500);
  });
```

but this doesn't work if I use js to add the html. I also tried:

```
$('.item').on( "click", function() {
   $(this).find('.hidden').toggle(500);
   });
```

and

```
$(document).on( "click", ".item", function() {
   $(this).find('.hidden').toggle(500);
   });
```

but when the js writes the html, it just doesn't work.
Any ideas?  I tried searching in vain but maybe I'm not searching for the right solution, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have to add the event handlers to the elements that were added via javascript.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "manually".  Please provide a detailed step by step explanation of what is happening.  Is the `$(".item).click(...)` running **after** you have added the HTML to the page with JS?

Comment: Have you tried "$(document).on('click','.item',function(){$(this).find('.hidden').toggle(500);})

Comment: By manually, I mean just adding the html to the document instead of having the js write it.

Comment: I tried using using  "$(document).on('click','.item',function(){$(this).find('.hi‌​dden').toggle(500);}‌​)" and "$('.item').on('click', function(){$(this).find('.hi‌​dden').toggle(500);}‌​)" but I'm running into the same issue, it doesn't work if js writes the the html.